# 14.04 my keyboard mapping is incorrect. How can I fix it?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I installed 14.04 from DVD and did no customization. Mouse works fine, but the keyboard is very messed up. <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> stays on and won't go off. Some keys work, other do not. So jlk works but asd do not. Fails in browser,terminal, and sublime. All worked fine under 12.0.

I tried Gear Menu > System Settings > Keyboard, but this has only shortcuts and typing.

I can't type dconf-editor as some have suggested, <kbd>D</kbd> key does not work.